# Unable to resolve dependencies for Intel x86 Atom System Image

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

I try download image by android studio, but I get an error:

Android Studio tells me "Unable to resolve dependencies for Intel x86 Atom System Image"

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Go to

> Help->Check for updates
>
> switch update channel to Canary

and then try opening sdk manager. Install the components and you are good to go.

Comment: @Xander please accept the solution if it solved the issue.